# Angular Reactive Form Group Issues with Lazy Loaded Components

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to Implement A Reactive form in one of the Lazy Loaded Component and I am getting the following error.

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-lazy-loading-gej1nn)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<h3>Product List</h3>

<form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="myForm">

    <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
"): ng:///ProductsRoutingModule/ProductListComponent.html@2:6
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<h3>Product List</h3>

<form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="myForm">

    <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
")
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular6-lazy-loading",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

**products.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { ProductsRoutingModule } from "./products-routing.module"; //Added
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductsRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class ProductsModule {}
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**product-list.component.html**

```
<h3>Product List</h3>

<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name"/>
</form>
```

I have imported the required modules in Lazy Loaded Module and App Module

```
{ ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
```

Any Idea about this? Is it a Bug?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-lazy-loading-gej1nn

Answer (score 3):

routing module should export RouterModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(productRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule { }
```

and then ProductsModule can import ProductsRoutingModule as follow

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductsRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ProductsComponent, ProductListComponent, ProductDetailComponent ]
})
export class ProductsModule {}
```

`declarations` should be provided in module which you will use in lazy loading, in this case into `ProductsModule`

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-lazy-loading-gpcvjc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fproducts%2Fproducts.module.ts)

updated

1. At ProductsRoutingModule you can provide router settings, but export of RouterModule not necessary it is just a way to provide `RouterModule` for `ProductsModule`. Alternatively you can provide `RouterModule` in import of `ProductsModule`. To be able use router module declarations need to provide `RouterModule` in one of way.
2. If you define declarations at `ProductsRoutingModule` you also should provide all dependencies in same module by `import`, but to make `declarations` be included in `ProductsModule` you also should export them via `exports`

so alternatively you can change both module like follow, you can even omit `RouterModule` while you have it in the main module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(productRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductsComponent, ProductListComponent, ProductDetailComponent
  ],
  exports: [    
    ProductsComponent, ProductListComponent, ProductDetailComponent
  ]
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ProductsRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class ProductsModule {}
```

could be interesting to read [modules-in-angular](https://indepth.dev/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular/) and [asynchronous-modules](https://indepth.dev/asynchronous-modules-and-components-in-angular-ivy/)

Comment: So the only change is 'routing module should export RouterModule' in ProductsRoutingModule ?

Comment: @MithunS no without `declarations` in `ProductsModule` it also will not work

Comment: Could you please explain the Reason behind this?

Comment: @MithunS i add some details

Answer (score 0):

move component declarations in product module instead of routing module

```
declarations: [ProductsComponent, ProductListComponent, ProductDetailComponent ]
```

Comment: Could you please explain the Reason behind this?

Comment: As you are loading the product module using `loadChildren: 'app/products/products.module#ProductsModule'` the components should be declared that module.

Answer (score 0):

I found two errors in the stackblitz code

1. The components in the feature module should be declared in the module referenced by the parent module. In your case `app.module` lazyloads `products.module`. But the components of products module was declared in `products-routing.module`
2. The router module should export the `RouterModule`
3. in `products.component` the template string was provided inside template literal(backtik) replace it to normal string `template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'`(quotes)

find the fixed code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-lazy-loading-cezgkf?embed=1&file=src/app/products/products.component.ts)